# How to call specific array values in v-for in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**User.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- <div class="cont-color">{{ user.name }} {{ user.age }}</div> -->

    <div v-for="(item, key) in user" :key="key">
      {{ item }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { datalisttwo } from "./datalisttwo";
export default {
  name: "User",
  data() {
    return {
      lists: datalisttwo,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    user: function () {
      return this.lists.find((item) => item.cmd_id === this.$route.params.id);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Working code:- https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-cartwright-vi6qg?file=/src/components/User.vue

How to call specific value from an array in Vuejs.

At present, It is calling all values, from an array. But want to call only {{name}} and {{age}} values.

If i remove the v-for and write directly like this  {{ user.name }} {{ user.age }} --> It is printing the array values, But getting error as

[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')"
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Comment: What does _call the url query params correctly for both arrays_ means? Whats is the current issue?

Comment: For my api endpoint url, i need to pass the query params. As stated above. for both arrays

Comment: At present issue is,Unable to call the query params dynamically. if i click on router-link, in the left hand side, i am unable to call the exact query params as stated above. and for right hand side, call query params by /id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is in your computed block, use below solution

```
computed: {
    user: function () {
      return this.lists.find((item) => item.cmd_id === this.$route.params.id);
    },
  },
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-darkness-vq2n5?file=/src/components/User.vue:257-383)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, With your solution, i have made few changes. here it is https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-yonath-50n77?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: If you can see in the url section it is now showing as, HelloWorld?pm_id=1 instead can i make like this, by writing / after HelloWorld.  **HelloWorld/?pm_id=1** then it gives correct url for me

Comment: Also for datalisttwo array, can i call query params like.... /id for getting values? please

Comment: HelloWorld/?pm_id=1 , its not convention,

Comment: For datalisttwo array. I have API like this http://35.162.202.237:3000/somename/id

So in frontend i need to show like by making api call, on click of each routerlink.  display values

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-pasteur-uxl19?file=/src/main.js  you can check, may you are asking something like this

Comment: Yes like this exactly. But in console it has some errors:-  [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')"
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Answer (score 1):

In **User.vue** you have this comparison:

```
return this.lists.find((item) => item.id === this.$route.params.id);
```

but the data you use from `datalisttwo.js` does not have the property `id` but instead `cmd_id`

So that find result will always be `undefined` which is the error you see in the javascript console:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')"
```

so you'll need to update your `find` to be the following:

```
return this.lists.find((item) => item.cmd_id === this.$route.params.id);
```

Comment: If you can see in the url section it is now showing as, HelloWorld?pm_id=1 instead can i make like this, by writing / after HelloWorld. HelloWorld/?pm_id=1 then it gives correct url for me.

And for datalisttwo array, query params are not calling, like User/id for getting values?

Comment: just for reference, `/?YourQueryParams=SomeValue` is the same as `?YourQueryParams=SomeValue`

they are both valid urls which will have the same effect

Comment: After making above changes, in the console i am getting some errors like [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')"
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-cartwright-vi6qg?file=/src/components/datalist.js

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to return an Array on that computed property. Use filter instead of find.

```
 computed: {
    user: function () {
      return this.lists.filter((item) => {
        if(item.cmd_id === this.$route.params.id) {
           return item
        }
      })
    }        
 }
```